# Prevent printing to offline printers

Tags: windows-7, windows, printing, printer

Is there some way to prevent printing to printers that are offline (possibly, but not necessarily by making them not able to be selected until they are online again)?

The situation is there is a printer at work and a printer at home and things get printed to the wrong printer.  Of course if we realize the wrong printer was selected we can delete the job and print to the correct one, but that doesn't always happen, and when bringing the laptop out of standby at the other location, something starts printing that wasn't intended to be printed there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to disable a printer (there seems to be no [command-line](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php) or UI option to do this that I can see).

One possible solution could be to schedule two tasks. One would set the work printer as the default in the morning, and the other would do the same for the home printer in the evening. That way wherever you are you can print to the default printer and be assured it'll be online.

The command to do this is any one of the following:

```
printui /y /n "printer name"
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "printer name"
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -t -p "printer name"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have premium edition of Windows 7, it supports location-aware printing, which means you can have different default printer set for different networks.

To manage location-aware printing settings:

1) Open **Devices and Printers** by clicking the **Start button**, and then, on the Start menu, clicking Devices and Printers.

2) Click a printer, and then click **Manage default printers** on the toolbar.

3) Click **Change my default printer when I change networks**.

Then you can set select default printer for each network listed. Also when you set some printer as default, it will do it only for the current network.

More info on [MS website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-switch-default-printers-between-home-work-or-school).

Comment: This is a nice solution, but unfortunately it doesn't affect programs that are already running that have printed to a printer already (I tried Chrome and MS Word).  Changing the default printer manually does affect MS Word, just not when done via this automated way.  I suppose one solution that would at least cover Word would be to use AutoHotKey to watch for a change in default printer and then run the script in Karan's answer to manually set the default printer (in the case of someone not working a fixed schedule).